# How would I delete all checked todos?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I wanted to know how I would delete all checked todos in my room database on the `RecyclerView`. I don't want to delete all the items in the table I just want to delete the ones that the user has clicked on the `CheckBox` for. And I also want to ensure that todos that have not been checked do not get deleted.

Checked todo example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY0lN.jpg

`MainActivity`:

```kotlin
package com.example.todoit

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.todoit.data.Todo
import com.example.todoit.data.TodoDataBase
import com.example.todoit.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter
    private lateinit var todoDB: TodoDataBase
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        todoDB = TodoDataBase.getInstance(this)
        todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(mutableListOf())

        val rvTodoItems = binding.rvTodoItems
        val btnAddTodo = binding.btnAddTodo
        val btnDeleteTodo = binding.btnDeleteTodo

        rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter

        btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
            val todoTitle = binding.etTodoTitle.text.toString()

            if (todoTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                val todo = Todo(null, todoTitle, false)

                GlobalScope.launch {
                    todoDB.todoDao().insertAll(todo)
                }

                todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)

                binding.etTodoTitle.text.clear()

                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully written data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "There was an error while writing data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        }


        btnDeleteTodo.setOnClickListener {
            todoAdapter.deleteDoneTodos()

            GlobalScope.launch {
                todoDB.todoDao().deleteAllCheckedTodos()
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Todo(s) Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

`TodoAdapter`:

```kotlin
package com.example.todoit

import android.graphics.Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.todoit.data.Todo
import com.example.todoit.data.TodoDataBase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_todo.view.*

class TodoAdapter(
    private val todos: MutableList<Todo>,
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    private lateinit var todoDB: TodoDataBase

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        return TodoViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_todo,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    fun addTodo(todo: Todo) {
        todos.add(todo)
        notifyItemInserted(todos.size - 1)
    }

    fun deleteDoneTodos() {
        todos.removeAll { todo ->
            todo.isChecked
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle: TextView, isChecked: Boolean) {

        if(isChecked) {
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG

        } else {
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val curTodo = todos[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
            cbDone.isChecked = curTodo.isChecked
            toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, curTodo.isChecked)
            cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, isChecked)
                curTodo.isChecked = !curTodo.isChecked
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }
}
```

`TodoDao`:

```kotlin
package com.example.todoit.data

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface TodoDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertAll(vararg todos: Todo)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM todo_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<List<Todo>>
}
```

If you need more code then please let me know. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is removing item from the `List` which wouldn't help since it's not applying any change to the database.

The better approach could be to use `@Delete` in the `Dao`

##### Add this to the DAO

```
@Delete
fun deleteAll(varargs todos: Todo)
```

##### TodoAdapter

```
fun deleteDoneNotes(){
    todoDB.deleteAll(*todos.filter { it.isChecked })
}
```

Comment: In the todoDao on the delete function is says that a type annotation is required on value parameter and how do I access the database on the adapter to delete the todos like is there a way to do todoDB = TodoDatabase.getInstance(this) to initalise the database in the adapter or is that not necessary?

Comment: my bad, use `todoDb.deleteAll(` instead,

Comment: What should I do about the other questions?